Moving a nested dataframe into one row of another dataframe in databricks
I am working with xml exports from databricks, and I need to have the data in a specific format. I already have a nested datastructure in a dataframe, and I have successfully exported it with my_df.write.xml(filename) but I need to put wrapper structures around it. It would be so best to do it all from databricks.
The following is a simplified example of what I have:
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, ArrayType

deeply_nested_schema = StructType([
    StructField("brand", StringType(), nullable=False),
    StructField("year", IntegerType(), nullable=False),
    StructField("extras", ArrayType(StringType()), nullable=True)
])
deeply_nested_data = [
    ("Toyota", 2020, ["GPS", "Bluetooth"]),
    ("Honda", 2019, ["Sunroof", "Leather seats"]),
    ("Ford", 2021, ["Backup camera", "Apple CarPlay"])
]
deeply_nested_df = spark.createDataFrame(deeply_nested_data, deeply_nested_schema)

Now, I want to put deeply_nested_df into ONE row of the "wrapper" structure:
journal_data = [(1)]
journal_schema = ["JournalID"]
journal_df = spark.createDataFrame(journal_data, journal_schema)

in order to produce:
journalid:integer
deeply_nested:array
  brand:string
  year:integer
  extras:array
    element:string

The amount of data is so large that using pandas is out of the question.
